# Can Container.ReplaceContainer impact the data in collection?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

There is `Container.ReplaceContainer` method in Cosmos DB SDK.

It is described as

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.replacecontainerasync?view=azure-dotnet):

```
Replace a ContainerProperties from the Azure Cosmos service as an asynchronous operation
```

and

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.cosmos_client.cosmosclient?view=azure-python#replacecontainer-collection-link--collection--options-none-):

```
Replaces a collection and return it.
```

Is there any chance to lost the data after such replacement ([examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy))?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my findings and test,it seems that `Update indexPolicy` will keep the availability of cosmos db.But the query will be affected because of the rebuilding of indexes.Please see the statements in the [document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3691N.png):

[image]